# C#.Заполнение DatagrirView

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет.  Как правильно настроить и работать с DataGridView, если структура datarow и грида различны? На данный момент заполняю грид методом `Add()`. Приведу пример кода:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(sName, sCount);
```

Данные для добавления берутся из `datarow []`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли заполнить грид быстрее?

Comment: Быстрее в смысле производительности или уменьшения объема кода?

Comment: В плане производительности. Думаю, что очевидна речь о скорости выполнения.

Comment: В плане производительности...Если данных _**действительно**_ много, то установите режим `VirtualMode = true` и обрабатывайте соответствующие события. Подробнее в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx). Но, полагаю, вам будет достаточно просто использовать обычную привязку данных.

Comment: По поводу обычной привязки можно поподробней?

Comment: `dgv.DataSource = datarows.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;`

Comment: Этот вариант для моей задачи не подойдет. Т.к. копирование не только таблицы, но и наименования колонок.

Comment: У вас хедеры для столбцов в `dgv` должны быть другие чем в `datarows` или что?

Comment: Да, они другие.

Comment: В чем проблема переименовать их так как вам хочется? Использовать `ColumnName` для `DataColumn` или уже менять сразу в `DataGridView`  через установку свойства `HeaderText` для `DataGridViewColumn`. Не говоря уже о том, что можно возвращать сразу псевдонимы из базы.

Comment: Используется SQLite. Что-то не припомню поддержку псевдонимов колонок. Поэтому псевдонимы отпадают. Последовательность столбцов другая, при этом структура результирующего запроса отличается от структуры грида.

Comment: да неужели... http://www.w3big.com/ru/sqlite/sqlite-alias.html

Comment: Не знал, что псевдоним на русском может быть. А что по второй части?

Comment: Вторую часть вопроса сразу не увидел. Что вы понимаете под `структура результирующего запроса отличается от структуры грида`? Вы всегда можете разделить данные на те части, которые вам нужны. Или сделать отдельный запрос для удобства.

Comment: В гриде: Фамилия, Имя, Отчество. В datarow: Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, ИД, Дата рождения и т.д.

Comment: Уважаемый Александр, вот, ИМХО, формулировка Вашего вопроса, при которой не будет ни одного возражения, а будет всеобщее удовольствие: как правильно настроить и работать с DataGridView, если структура datarow и грида различны? :)

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Буду не спешить при формулировке вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В комменатриях промелькнула информация, что загрузка из DataSource не используется из-за того, что стуктура результирующего запроса отличается от структуры DataGridViev.

Это не проблема, можно ручками управлять привязываемыми колонками, выбирая, какую колонку из источника отобразить на конкретной колонке DataGridView.

```
 dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;//Колонки генерироваться не будут=> где-то потребуется их сгенерировать перед привязкой
    dataGridView.DataSource = result;
    dataGridView.Columns["GridColumnName"].DataPropertyName = "ResultColumnName";
```

Данные, которые не были привязаны не теряются.

Т.е, получив Row из DataGridView вы ее можете привести к нужному типу и обратится к полям, которые не были отражены.

Comment: Что тут сказать... Твой ответ решил не один вопрос. Заполняю через DataSource. Все круто, совет идеален. Если не сложно, можешь дать совет по вопросу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614114/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-bindingsource

Answer (score 1):

В идеале ДатаГрид или ДатаГридВью валью не должны заполнятся в принципе.

В идеале нужно переключить в режим виртуального ( VirtualMode = true ) и подгружать данные напрямую с любого соурса данных. Будь то датасет, аррей стрингов, лист кастомных обьектов иль что еще.

То есть в dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded пишешь каким именно макаром нужно доставать и обрабатывать данные. И все ли нужно вставлять из реально имеющихся данных.

В том числе можно подгружать данные напрямую с SQL.

Comment: Все из имеющихся данных высталять не нужно.

Comment: ну тогда делаешь выборку нужную. Вроде DataGrid.Cells['colColName'] = sql_item.ValueForThisColumn. Ничего особенно сложного, разберешься.