# Запрос к BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Есть необходимость выбрать 100 записей пропустив 500. Может кто подскажет, можно ли сделать offset и limit для BindingSource?

Comment: попробуйте BindingSource.Filter

Comment: Хорошо, но не вижу каким образом можно сие реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение зависит от источника данных.

Если это DataTable, то можно воспользоваться View и отфильтровать по какому-то критерию. Можно и так `dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(n).Take(t).CopyToDataTable()`
Получается, что ты пропускаешь n строк и берешь t. Перемещаясь на другую страницу ты увеличиваешь n. Нужно хранить помнить значение n.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248616/paging-to-list-previous-set-of-values-form-datatable-in-c-sharp) показан пример, как это можно реализовать, если нет доступа к LINQ.

В двух словах: создаешь метод, который будет явно перебирать циклами без LINQ исходную коллекцию.

Если это коллекция объектов, то можно создать новую коллекцию вызвав `Skip(n).Take(t)`.

Если доступа к LINQ есть, то выше ссылка так же поможет реализовать тебе эту логику.

Comment: Источник DataSet. Критерием, как я понял, порядковый номер может быть?

Comment: Ну из DataSet ты выбираешь же определенную таблицу=> по факту DataTable.

Comment: Да, так и есть.

Comment: Суть в том, что я хочу организовать страничное представление данных.. Мой грид привязан к BindingSource.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Пробую так dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(n).Take(t) , но возвращает пустые строки

Comment: Использую этот код dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(n).Take(t), выводит пустые строки. Не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, я не уверен, но может быть дело в отложенном выполнении. Вы проверяли возвращаемую коллекцию в дебаггере?

Comment: Разобрался, в приме, что привел не хватает метода .CopyToDataTable(). Подредактируй ответ.

Comment: А так спасибо, огромное. Ответ что надо.